# Why does my production datastore have indexes that are not included in index.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When running my application locally against dev_appserver.py, the indexes listed on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/admin/datastore_indexes` exactly match those listed in my `index.yaml` file.  However, when I look at my production indexes at https://appengine.google.com/datastore/indexes, there are a few additional indexes that show up on the dashboard that do not exist in the `index.yaml`.

Why is this?  Does the production appengine auto-generate new indexes like dev_appserver.py does?  Or are these "leftover" indexes that I should delete if I know they are no longer in use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will be "leftover" indexes. The production server will only *add* new indexes it finds in index.yaml, it won't delete old ones (different versions of your app might have different index requirements).

You can run `appcfg.py vacuum_indexes .` from your app's directory, and it will prompt you to delete any that are present on the server but missing from index.yaml

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to delete unused indexes. New indexes are auto-generated, but we leave the decision on when to clean up to you (since we're not in the position of knowing when you'll be switching between versions of your app).

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Updating_Indexes and  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Deleting_Unused_Indexes